# Command to create MySQL database with Character set UTF-8

Tags: mysql, database, command, utf-8, charset

I use `create database dbname;` to create database.
 but I want it to created with Character set UTF-8

Anyone know what is the command to use?

Comment: note that the database charset is only part of the picture: you have to also set the server and client connection charsets

Answer (score 26):

Use the

```
CHARACTER SET
```

option when creating your database, like so:

```
CREATE DATABASE dbname CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

also, [read the docs...](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-database.html)

Answer (score 17):

If database name contains nonalphanumeric chars use "`" to quote:

```
CREATE DATABASE `my-db` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

When using in shell script quote the quotes with "\"

```
mysql -p -e "CREATE DATABASE \`my-db\` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;"
```